# Why Does Setting Debug=False Stop Controls Functioning?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET website which has been functioning perfectly well for months. Today I was reading about how important it is to set the debug value in the web.Config file on the production web server to False, so I gave it a try on a test copy of the site first.  Upon doing so, however, whilst most things at first glance seemed ok, for some reason most if not all (I haven't done a comprehensive recce) of the controls within UpdatePanels on my pages stopped working.  I'd click buttons but nothing would happen.  As soon as I change back to Debug=True, they work again.

Why would changing the debug mode of the site stop controls from working?

Comment: Never happend that to me... I always use debug=false on final server. Maybe they are some other issues, maybe your controls did not fully updated with the new flag ? Is your project big one ? Maybe a new clean up needed when you change the flag because the compiler fail to update all... because of some optimization....

Answer (score 0):

Changing modes can affect code, as the compiler optimizes code when in `Release` mode. There are ways around it:

[Debug vs. Release - The Best of Both Worlds](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DebugVsReleaseTheBestOfBothWorlds.aspx)